# What does _NR stand for in system call number ?That is usually used as suffix

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

Can anyone tell me what does NR stand for? 
eg:
  #define _NR_exit

I've being looking everywhere but i could not find an answer.

Comment: I looked at all the Linux kernel source code, Googled extensively and came up only with [others asking the same question](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/system-call-naming-convention-853458/) and not getting an answer too

Comment: THE FULL FORM OF _NR is Numeric Reference ..its a macro :)

Answer (score 15):

This dates back to [Linux 0.01](http://lxr.linux.no/linux-old+v0.01/) (see [`include/unistd.h`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux-old+v0.01/include/unistd.h#L60)).

In [`kernel/system_call.s`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux-old+v0.01/kernel/system_call.s#L48) is the line:

```
nr_system_calls = 67
```

and [`include/linux/sched.h`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux-old+v0.01/include/linux/sched.h#L4) has:

```
#define NR_TASKS 64
```

and [`include/linux/fs.h`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux-old+v0.01/include/linux/fs.h#L40) has a whole bunch of other `NR_xxx` constants.

In all these cases, "nr" is clearly being used as an abbreviation for "number".

I reckon that's reasonably strong evidence that Mircea Gherzan's guess of "Can't it be NumbeR ?" in the comments above is correct.

Comment: i will wait for few more days...i guess u both are correct...i couldn't find a concrete answer anywhere.Thank You for your time.

Comment: THE FULL FORM OF _NR is Numeric Reference ..its a macro :)

Answer (score 8):

THE FULL FORM OF _NR  is Numeric Reference ..its a macro :)